# How to make ObjectInputStream read all objects from file in java?

Tags: java

I have a file which is storing objects and I have a `*getAll()` method which needs to return the `List<Secretary>`. But, I only see single object being printed in console.
I searched for the problem and tried **3 ways** but it did not work.

The insert method for inserting object in file is:

```
@Override
    public Secretary insert(Secretary t) {
        try { 
            System.out.println("insert called");
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream 
                                           (filename,true); 
        
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream 
                                           (file); 
  
             Method for serialization of object 
            out.writeObject(t); 
  
            out.close(); 
            file.close(); 
  
            return t;       
        } 
  
       catch (IOException ex) { 
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
  
        return null;
    }
```

I have declared append mode as true as, my file was being replaced by new object when saving.

So,i need to fetch all object from file and need to assign to a list.I tried:

```
public class SecretaryDaoImpl implements SecretaryDAO{

    private  String filename = "secretary.txt";
    private Secretary sec=null;
    @Override
        public List<Secretary> getAll() {
    //Method 1  
            
     try { 
     
                Reading the object from a file 
               FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream 
                                            (filename); 
               ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream 
                                            (file); 
                List<Secretary> secList=new ArrayList<>();
                 Method for deserialization of object 
               secList.add((Secretary)in.readObject()); 
      
               in.close(); 
                file.close(); 
              System.out.println("Object has been deserialized\n"
                                    + "Data after Deserialization."); 
                 
           System.out.println("secList is" +secList);
              return secList;
               
            } 
     
            catch (IOException ex) { 
                System.out.println("Secreatary file not found");
                return null;
            } 
      
            catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { 
               System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException" + 
                                    " is caught"); 
           } 
             return null;
    
    //Method 2  
              List<Secretary> secList=new ArrayList<>();
            ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = null;
            try {
        FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
        objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(streamIn);
        List<Secretary> readCase = (List<Secretary>) objectinputstream.readObject();
        for(Secretary s:readCase){
            secList.add(s);
        }
        System.out.println("seclist is" + secList);
        return secList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(objectinputstream != null){
            try {
                objectinputstream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SecretaryDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
    }
    //Method 3
            try{
             File file = new File(filename);
            List<Secretary> list = new ArrayList<>();
            if (file.exists()) {
                try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
                    list.add((Secretary) ois.readObject());
                }
            }
                System.out.println("getall is"+list);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

I have commented out my code but here while posting in stackoverflow I have uncommented all the codes.
My Secretary.java is :

```
package com.npsc.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashwin
 */
public class Secretary implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6529685098267757690L;
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private Branch branch;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Secretary(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        
    }

    public Branch getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Secretary{" + "id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + ", password=" + password + ", branch=" + branch + '}';
    }
    
    
    
}
```

While performing insert operation,my txt file saving objects is:
[image]

But,I am unable to read all the object and add in list.Where I am facing the problem?

Comment: You only call `secList.add((Secretary)in.readObject())` once.  How do you expect `secList` to contain multiple objects?

Comment: yes ,so I am asking how can put all object in list ? I am not able to iterate all over the file and put all objects in list

Comment: I understand the extend of your question now - I've added an answer to illustrate how to store the number of objects to be read from persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store in the file, the number of Secretary objects to read back.  You can then determine how many entities to read, and thus repopulate your list.

Something like:

```
List<Secretary> list;
private void persistList(ObjectOutputStream out) {
   out.writeInt(list.size());
   for (Secretary sec : list) {
      out.writeObject(sec);
   }
}
```

And then to read:

```
private List<Secretary> readFromStream(ObjectInputStream in) {
   int numObjects = in.readInt();
   List<Secretary> result = new ArrayList<>(numObjects);
   for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
      result.add((Secretary)in.readObject());
   }
   return result;
}
```

This is just a sketch of the technique (and ignores error handling, stream opening/closing etc.); the main thing is to integrate the idea of recording the size of the list, then reading *that many* Secretaries into your existing code.

Comment: do you mean that the way I am storing object in file is wrong?

Comment: while I call the insert method,then I only pass a single object not the whole list of Secretary

Comment: @AshwinKarki If you're only storing *one* Secretary object in the file - how you do expect to read more than one out of it?  They all need to be in there for you to read back...

Comment: is your  syntax result.append correct? I think its result.add?

Comment: You're right (I've been working with other languages this week and got mixed up.  Use IDEs, kids!)

Comment: In that insert function,at a instance I only save a object not  a list. But u r providing list to be saved at file. Please can you modify so that i can save an object to the file

Comment: still i am not getting the list of objects

Comment: sorry the way you are posting the answer,even object are not being inserted in file

Comment: @AshwinKarki - this isn't intended to be a drop-in piece of code you can use of the bat.  It illustrates the concept that you need to persist the number of elements (as well as each element), so that when you come to read the file you know how many times to call `readObject()`.  You will need to integrate that approach yourself into your existing codebase.

Comment: I have integrated your code to mine.Do you wanna see and help me if u want then i will post the edited codes

Comment: This does not solve the problem. From the code snippet provided by @AshwinKarki, he adds objects to the file independently, not all at once. Then he wants to read all objects from the file. So this mean if he executes insert(Secretary t)  like 5 times for example, he will have added 5 objects to the file. Now he wants to read them. I am facing the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Write a `List<Secretary>` to file and read same back, then you will have all.

```
write (Secretary s) {
 read List<Secretary> currentList ;
 currentList.add(s)
 write List<Secretary> 
}
```

Comment: Firstly which List implementations are serializable? Secondly the OP wants to progressively add objects to the file.